# Foundation dark theme

Tags: html, web, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I want to create a dark theme for foundation by zurb, with a dark background and light writing. I can not find a way to change the project settings to do so, so I have been editing the generated CSS files, which is not ideal. I expect I might be able to edit the sass files to have a dark theme, but I was hoping there was some configuration I can do instead of all that.

The relevant part of the settings file, I can not figure out how to make the background dark...

```
// Colors Settings

// $mainColor: #2ba6cb;
// $secondaryColor: #e9e9e9;
// $alertColor: #c60f13;
// $successColor: #5da423;
// $txtColor: #222;
// $highlightColor: #ffff99;
// $black: #000;
// $white: #fff;
// $shinyEdge: rgba(#fff, .5);
// $darkEdge: rgba(#000, .2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking in the right place. You just need to uncomment those lines, eg:

```
// Colors Settings

// $mainColor: #2ba6cb;
// $secondaryColor: #e9e9e9;
// $aler...
```

Should be like this:

```
// Colors Settings

$mainColor: #000000;
// $secondaryColor: #e9e9e9;
// $aler...
```

With regards to changing the background colour, I think you will have to do this as part of app.scss, what I do is add other colour settings to my settings.scss file and then use these in app.scss:

```
// Colors Settings

$background:#000000;
$mainColor: #000000;
// $secondaryColor: #e9e9e9;
// $aler...

body,html {
    background:$background;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right area.

If you have a look at _global.scss you can see on line 7:

```
body { background: $white; font-family: $bodyFontFamily; font-weight: $bodyFontWeight; font-style: $bodyFontStyle; font-size: ms(0); line-height: 1; color: $bodyFontColor; position: relative; -webkit-font-smoothing: $fontSmoothing; }
```

Basically the background is being set to the `$white;`

`$white` then appears in LOTS of different areas in the scss files so you can either

1. update the `$white` variable to a dark colour and see how it looks
2. create a new variable for the `$dark` colour and update line 7 to reference the new variable.